# Commands not working resp. could't be found even though $PATH is set correct?

Tags: linux, centos, path

Im using VirtualBox for a few weeks and my CentOS 7 worked fine. Suddenly the commands can't be found:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig
-bash: ifconfig: command not found
[root@localhost ~]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
[root@localhost ~]# which ifconfig
/usr/bin/which: no ifconfig in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
```

I have no clue why suddenly the commands are not working. I can't remember doing "radical" changes. 
Even with a complete new installation the issue persists! How can that be?
Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ifconfig` is considered deprecated in CentOS 7, and thus won't be installed when installing the 'minimal' software group.

You can install it with `yum install net-tools -y`, however, you should be using the `ip` command to do your network administration (which is installed in the base installation of CentOS 7).

Comment: Yeah. That was correct! I'm still not quite sure how this happend, maybe via the last update. But e.g. "nslookup" and "ifconfig" didn't work. They work after installing the correct package. Thank you.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem; please mark it as the correct answer with the green checkmark on the left. This way other people can easily find it.